# Allow user to dynamically select a box of pixels in a image shown on a webpage

Tags: javascript, python, html, css

I apologize in advance for the vague subject. I'm essentially looking for tutorial/guidance on the ability to dynamically select a grid of pixels within an image on a web page. What would be the best way to capture the grid of pixels the user dynamically selects?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do it in Javascript. There are different libraries and plugins available.
Just one as an example: http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/

Comment: Thanks this was exactly what I was looking for... do you know if it's possible to do multiple area selects?